# JQuery each function toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have some code like this

```
<ul>
<li>Example</li> 

<li>Example</li>

<li>Example
<a href="#" class="SplitCtrl"> > </a>
<div class="Menu" style="display:none;">
Some thing
</div>
</li>

<li>Example
<a href="#" class="SplitCtrl"> > </a>
<div class="Menu" style="display:none;">
Some thing
</div>
</li>

<li>Example</li>
</ul>
```

Then i use a JS code like this

```
$("ul li .SplitCtrl").each(function(index) {
$(this).on("click", function(){
    $(".Menu").fadeIn(800).slideDown(800);
});
});
```

But when i using this, all the ".Menu" element will be fade in :(
Please correct my code...

Comment: What is your desired behavior?

Comment: as the code, I want that when i click the ".SplitCtrl" then the ".Menu" will be fade in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the specific `.Menu` that is the one next to `this`. ELse it will target all element with `.Menu` class. You can use jquery [**next**](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$("ul li .SplitCtrl").each(function(index) {
$(this).on("click", function(){  //changed here
    $(this).next(".Menu").fadeIn(800).slideDown(800);
});
});
```

Check out this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gg9g9h7m/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't know which element to open because there are no id's assigned to the menu items.  So it opens everything in the .SplitCtrl class because it doesn't know any better.  If you assign some id's to the elements, then it will know what to open and when.  Using your code so as to minimize modifications, the following will work for you.  Note the addition of id's to *both* of the .SplitCtrl items and the .Menu items, and using the *click* function and passing in the id of the item that the click originated from.  If you embed further elements, this will still work in the case that it isn't the *next* element following your class, or if you want it to trigger other items on the page in addition to the menu items.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>Example</li> 

<li>Example</li>

<li>Example
<a href="#" class="SplitCtrl" id="1"> > </a>
<div class="Menu" id="menu1" style="display:none;">
Some thing
</div>
</li>

<li>Example
<a href="#" class="SplitCtrl" id="2"> > </a>
<div class="Menu" id="menu2" style="display:none;">
Some thing
</div>
</li>

<li>Example</li>
</ul>

<div id="surprise1" style="display:none;">Now I'm open too!</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li .SplitCtrl").click(function(event){
        var item = '#menu' + event.target.id;
        var surprise = '#surprise' + event.target.id;
        $(item).fadeIn(800).slideDown(800); // open the menu item
        $(surprise).fadeIn(800).slideDown(800);  // open another element
    });
});
</script>
```

In order to toggle the items, you can add something that first hides everything that's open and then makes the newly selected item visible:

```
//...same code as above to this point

<div id="surprise1" class="Surprise" style="display:none;">Now I'm open too!</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li .SplitCtrl").click(function(event){
        var item = '#menu' + event.target.id;
        var surprise = '#surprise' + event.target.id;
        $(".Menu").fadeOut(100); // Hide all items of class .Menu
        $(".Surprise").fadeOut(100); // Hide other items of class .Surprise
        $(item).fadeIn(800).slideDown(800); // open the menu item
        $(surprise).fadeIn(800).slideDown(800);  // open another element
    });
});
</script>
```

So now, all the .Menu items in that class are toggled off before the new one is displayed (even though only one displays at a time). Note the added class for "Surprise" to be able to hide all the external elements as well.  There are lots of ways to toggle items so this is just one way you could accomplish it.

Comment: You're welcome!  I added a quick update that lets you control additional document elements with the same click, cheers!

Comment: I want that when i fade in a ".Menu", then it'll fade out another one if it has already display. How can i do it, sir?